# If you had a 100 qubit fully fault-tolerant quantum computer, what would you do?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, error-correction

As quantum computers improve, eventually we may have error-corrected devices that have very low error rate. However, many applications (Shor's algorithm, quantum chemistry) appear to require thousands of error-corrected qubits, if not more. Are there any promising examples in a lower qubit range of a few hundred fault-tolerant qubits, where it could truly be useful to society? The only concrete one I am aware of is Fermi-Hubbard model simulation, which might lie in this range.